# Problems running turtlesim_node with hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run turtlesim_node with hydro.  I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with roscore running.  Every time I try to run the node I get: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139916/problems-running-turtlesim_node-with-hydro/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2